# Elasticsearch update same document simultaneous results in VersionConflictEngineException

Tags: php, elasticsearch, queue, elastica

My workers process objects and the write them to mysql and elasticsearch, now it happens that 2 (or multiple workers) process similar objects and update the same ES document.

Resulting in the following error:

```
VersionConflictEngineException[[test][4] [seller][2678449]: version conflict, current [18], provided [17]]
```

I did some research and tried to use the `retry_on_conflict` option but this resulted in the following error:

```
ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both retry_on_conflict and a specific version;]
```

I use [Elastica](http://elastica.io) version [1.2.1](http://elastica.io/2014/06/14/release-v1-dot-2-1-dot-0/)
And Elasticsearch version 1.2.1